# How to query for a zero-byte char?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

[According to the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/catalog-pg-attribute.html), `pg_attribute.attgenerated` is typed as `char` and has a value of "a zero byte" if the column is not generated, and there is at least one other possible value, with potentially more in the future.

I want to query for all non-generated columns.  Since I would prefer to not be tripped up by additions in future versions, the query predicate needs to be `WHERE attgenerated = ZERO BYTE` rather than an inequality, but I have no idea how to represent that value correctly in SQL.

What's the correct way to write this?  In most programming languages you'd say `'\0'`, and you can use escape sequences by prepending an `e` to the string literal, but if I say `e'\0'` it errors out with "invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00".  So I'm not quite sure what the right way to do this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply an empty string:

```
WHERE attgenerated = ''
```

Comment: The strange wording in the documentation is because the data type is the internal `"char"`.